# JavaFX OnMouseDragged

Tags: javafx

I try create google calendar in JavaFX but i have problem with setOnMouseDragged. My class create calendar event.

```
public class Events extends Pane {

public Events(Double x, Double y, String name) {

    Rectangle events = new Rectangle();
    events.setWidth(100);
    events.setHeight(50);
    Label label = new Label(name);

    this.getChildren().addAll(events, label);
    this.setLayoutX(x - 40);
    this.setLayoutY(y);

    this.setOnMouseDragged(m -> {
        System.out.println(m.getX() + " " + m.getY());
        this.setLayoutX(m.getX());
        this.setLayoutY(m.getY());

    });
}
```

And when I drag my event i have this:
[image]

what's interesting when it changes getX to getSceneX everything is ok. After the logs I see that there is a double stall: After the logs I see that there is a double drag: 
Dragged
44.0 20.0
Dragged
176.0 29.0

any suggestion ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Event's `x` and `y` properties are coordinates in the coordinate system of the node itself but `layoutX` and `layoutY` determine the position in the parent node.

You could transform to parent coordinates to get the desired effect.

```
Point2D mouseInParent = this.localToParent(m.getX(), m.getY());
this.setLayoutX(mouseInParent.getX());
this.setLayoutY(mouseInParent.getY());
```

Comment: Thank you very much